# Issues with roofing in cold weather?

Tags: roofing, shingles

I've got a crew of workers at my house putting on a new roof, in 25 degree weather.

The contractor said it wouldn't be a problem, although part of me wonders if he just didn't want his crew sitting idle.

Is this an issue?  Will the shingles be able to seal properly?

The weather is expected to warm to the low 40s in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shingles will eventually seal, but it will take more than 40 degrees to do so, although it may start the process. As long as there are not protruding nail heads and everything looks straight, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: If the wind does not blow them off before they seal.

Comment: I have seen many homes done in cold weather, it takes a few days of warm weather for things to relax and seal but if not in a windy area like blacksmith warns it should be fine.+